# Screen doesn't work properly - iPhone SE

Tags: ios, screen, touchscreen, iphone

I have an iPhone SE in almost perfect conditions (I never dropped it). I bought it 9 months ago, but since 3 weeks (and maybe more) the touch screen don't always works, I mean that when I touch, sometimes it doesn't understand that I'm touching, and that's very very annoying. The problem happened at least 1 time per hours and I already tried to clean the screen and restart my iPhone, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a screen protector on the phone?

Comment: Nope  @owlswipe I have no screen protector

Comment: Well, sounds like a hardware issue! You'll need support from Apple for this one, head to [getsupport.apple.com](https://getsupport.apple.com) or bring your phone in to the Apple Store.

Comment: Can't guarantee it, but my guess is they won't charge you for whatever necessary fix–so long as you can reproduce the issue for them. I would just try!

Comment: Arthur did apple fix this?  Do you know what hardware part they replaced?

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman No, they didn't replace anything. The issue was with a Chinese charger that was basically overheating the phone. Now it works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a screen protector or case on your phone, try removing them as that may be your issue.

Otherwise, it's most likely a hardware issue. Head to [getsupport.apple.com](https://getsupport.apple.com) to get help from Apple or visit a nearby Apple store.